# Relative copying from page to page in an Excel workbook

Tags: worksheet-function

I would like to generate a sequence of pages with formulae that reference a value on the previous page: a cell on page 6 will reference 5, and the same cell on page 5 will reference a cell on page 4, etc.  I am trying to generate a sequence of daily reports that will carry dates and values to subsequent pages.

Comment: How your data look like? What you've tried? How it didn't work?...

Comment: Is the sheet name = Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3? or..  renamed to something else?